# Laravel 5 issue with executing query with DB::select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've a query which perfectly works in phpmyadmin sql, but when I try to run the query in laravel 5 `DB::select` it gives me an error here is the code:

```
public function getCheckDueCurrentMonth()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM history_card WHERE DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE BETWEEN  NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE MAX(HISTORY_ID) GROUP BY  SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE DESC";

        $results = DB::select( DB::raw($query)); 
        return $results;


    }
```

here is the error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL 
 syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to 
use near 
'WHERE MAX(HISTORY_ID) GROUP BY SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE DESC)' 
at line 1 (SQL: (SELECT * FROM history_card WHERE DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE BETWEEN NOW() 
AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE MAX(HISTORY_ID) 
GROUP BY SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE DESC))
```

Comment: You only need one WHERE. Change the second to an AND/OR, and give it something to compare to.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
public function getCheckDueCurrentMonth()
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM history_card WHERE DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE BETWEEN  NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE MAX(HISTORY_ID) GROUP BY  SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE DESC";

            $results = DB::Raw($query); 
            return $results;


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're query is wrong. As I mentioned in my comment, queries can only have 1 WHERE. Join multiple clauses with AND, or OR.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM history_card 
    WHERE DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE BETWEEN  NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)     
    AND MAX(HISTORY_ID) 
    GROUP BY  SERIAL_NUMBER 
    ORDER BY DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE DESC";
```

I'm guessing you want only the last history_id, so you need to add that to the comparison:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM history_card 
    WHERE DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE BETWEEN  NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    AND history_id = MAX(HISTORY_ID) 
    GROUP BY  SERIAL_NUMBER 
    ORDER BY DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE DESC";
```

DB::raw is usually when you're doing column comparison or MySQL functions with `DB::select()->where()....`, so you can drop it here.

```
$results = DB::select( $query);
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM history_card 
    WHERE DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE BETWEEN  NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    AND history_id = MAX(HISTORY_ID) ` this query gives me error: Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that laravel 5 uses 'strict mode' in MySQL , if you would like to disable that, go to database.php in MySQL find `'strict' => true` and turn it to `'strict' => false`

Comment: I have same problem in laravel 5.1 and mysql 5.7. strict already false in database.php.. any other solutions